# what does null mean as parameter in JOptionPane.showMessageDialog

Tags: java, joptionpane

```
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "a String");
```

I was just wondering what the first argument (null) means in the JOptionPane line and what purpose does it serve?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object)

Comment: reading the documentation will probably give you the answer - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon%29) :

Concerning the first argument:

> parentComponent - determines the Frame in which the dialog is
>   displayed; if null, or if the parentComponent has no Frame, a default
>   Frame is used.

Answer (score 1):

The signature you're using is:

```
showInputDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message)
```

Which, according to java doc:

> Shows a question-message dialog requesting input from the user
>   `parented` to `parentComponent`.

Passing null to it just indicates that there's not an associated "parent" dialog - ie, the dialog being displayed does not belong to another dialog.

Instead, you can use the overloaded signature and call it like this:

```
showInputDialog(Object message)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message).
```

As you can see, the method "showMessageDialog()" requires two arguments: The first is of the Component type and the second is of the Object type. The "empty" value for a primitive int type would be "0", but the "empty" value for an Object or Component and so on is "null". Therefore, if you don't have any Component to choose, null is what you put there. If you specify a Component there, the Dialog will open on it. If you don't specify, you'll need to put null there, and the Dialog will open on "nothing"